# Python when I run my code, how can I split my screen into parts and have them print out multiple things

Tags: python

I would like to code a text-based rpg game.

On one side, it would show whatever the player is doing

Such as farming, fighting,...etc

and maybe on one side it would show players action history and whenever
the height of this screen goes over the monitors screen, it would delete the top one
in order to keep the screen same

I have no Idea how to approach to this, I've searched up "Python how to split screen" But
none of them seem to answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a framework allowing you to manage a **TUI** (Terminal User Interface or Text-Based User Interface). Several do so, such as [PyTermGUI](https://github.com/bczsalba/pytermgui), or [curses](https://docs.python.org/fr/dev/howto/curses.html).

These will allow you to manage your terminal as you would windows with [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/tkinter.html) for example.